# Bug during image upload

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today during uploading an image, I faced a problem and the image could not be uploaded. I have taken the screenshot. here is it:

[image]

I request diamond mods to look into this issue!

Comment: I'll see if I can ping a dev.

Comment: Can you give a link to the image so we don't have to type it out? This probably happens when the MIME type is not set. (also, IIRC, SVG files aren't supported)

Comment: The link is [here](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm2099689984/tt1758429)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dig through the page source for jpg's, you can often find the link to the photo.

Using Mozilla, I clicked on Firefox, Web Developer, Page Source, then searched for jpg links. In IE, you can right-click on the page, choose View Source, then search for jpg links. Sometimes there is more than one photo, so you may have to test them out to find the right one.

I found this one:

[http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNjc2MzYzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTA0MTQ1NA@@.*V1*.jpg](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMwNjc2MzYzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTA0MTQ1NA@@._V1_.jpg)

[image]

Is that the one you were after?

Comment: Ah! Great find! You finally did it! I too use Mozilla! :)

Comment: Of course, you would want to cite the source, which you could easily do by also including a link to the page the photo came from.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that you are not linking to a photo. That link (at least when I cut an paste your link in the comments) brings me to a web page. You need to link directly to a .png, .jpg or whatever other image formats are supported.

Comment: It seems IMDB does not give its image explicitly, rather links to a page where the image exists. So in such scenarios is there no way we can do it?

Comment: @Mistu4u That is probably by design on their part. I'm speculating that they do not *want* you to deep link their images for use outside their services. There may be some HTML wizardry to work around it, or you could capture and store it as a new image stored elsewhere, but if it thwarts their usage policy, please do not do that.